# "make a contraction" vs. "make contractions"

Tags: word-usage

[From a tutorial (Transcript)](https://youtu.be/S2aoN4nOCTA?list=PLD6t6ckHsrubLp8Ia8duzu5fN4riM2-Bl&t=29)

> He is --> He’s They will --> They’ll
> Do not --> Don’t But which words can you **make contractions from**?

[image]

I understand the rules of contractions. I'd just like to know whether I should singular when talking about just one occurrence.

For example,

> He is --> He’s

should I say

> make a contraction from "He is"

or

> make contractions from "He is"

Is what I get, "he's", the contraction?

Are there any other expressions clearer and more natural could be used here?

Comment: *Which words can you make contractions from?* is "ugly, awkward" phrasing that most native speakers would avoid, and I don't think any alternatives to ***make*** *(**form, construct, create,...**)* would be much better. I'd rather ask something like *Which words can be contracted?*

Comment: I agree with Monica. ***Morphology** could be applied in case if the context becomes verbose and rather fuzzy.*

Comment: @AlexRaw Thank you. Does "Morphology" here mean [a branch of linguistics](https://www.thoughtco.com/morphology-words-term-1691407#:~:text=Morphology%20is%20the%20branch%20of,form%20words%2C%20such%20as%20affixes.)?

Answer (score -1):

> I'd just like to know whether I should singular when talking about just one occurrence.

Since we are taking about one specific contraction here, we will use **the contraction**.

> should I say
>
> make a contraction from "He is"?

That doesn’t sound natural.

---

Consider these:

What is the contraction for “he is”?

- The contraction for *he is* is *he’s*.

What is the contraction for “do not”?

- The contraction for *do not* is *don’t*.